# Return true if input matches any string from web request output

Tags: typescript

I need the following code to return `true` if the `const ip_address` (`string`) exists in the output from `const request`.

```
function getBlocklist() {
    const baseurl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/bi_sip_0_1d.ipset"
    const request = require('request');
    request(baseurl, function (error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    })
}
getBlocklist()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn the request part into a `promise` and check if the variable you are looking for exists.

```
async function getBlocklist() {
        const baseurl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/bi_sip_0_1d.ipset"
        const request = require('request');
    
        const IssueRequest = ()=>{
          return new promise ((resolve)=>{
                request(baseurl, function (error, response, body){
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        if (body.output.ip_address){
                             resolve(true);
                       }else{
                         resolve(false);
                       }
                    }
                })
            
            });
        }
      return await IssueRequest();
    }
```

Comment: With this I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip_address' of undefined` - is there a certain way that I need to make `ip_address` usable in this const?

Comment: above this, I have `const ip_address = process.argv[2];` defined

Comment: comment out the if conditions and `console.log(body)` show me the results and change `const ip_address` to `let ip_address` if you wanna re-assign it.

Comment: the body output is too long to put here, but it's viewable here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/bi_sip_0_1d.ipset

Comment: but that ^ raw output is the result of `console.log(body)`

Comment: alright, you just have to check which value you want to put in this `ip_address` which exists in the body. I see that body is not a JSON object. so just make a script to check for the ip_address you are looking for and if it exists `resolve(true)` so the code is the staying the same.

Comment: By "stays the same", you mean stays the same as what i had it originally? - and "just make a script to check for the ip_address you are looking for and if it exists resolve(true)", isn't that what this is supposed to be?

Comment: This worked, provided I modified the if statement to `if (body.search(re) == -1 )` to match a regex search of `ip_address`